# Connect SQLiteHelper with another source file

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLiteHelper source file that I use to create the database, data, and all that. I have another source file that needs to get the data created by the SQLiteHelper source file. How can I accomplish that? To be more specific, how can I connect the two source files? GetReadableDatabase() can't be used without me pointing it to the database created by SQLiteHelper (how do I point it to the database?) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the standard CRUD operations in your SQLiteOpenHelper class, and then instantiate your SQLite Helper in your activity(it might be better to use a single static instance). Acces your Database through that instance.

This is a snippet of a Helper class I used a while back for a Facebook CHAT Application.

```
/**
 * @author vinaysshenoy
 * Manages all database aspects
 */
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        //Database properties
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        //Database Table Names
        public static final String TABLE_FRIENDS = "Friends";
        public static final String TABLE_CONVERSATIONS = "Conversations";

        //Friends Table Columns
        public static final String FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_USER_ID = "fb_user_id";
        public static final String FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_USERNAME = "fb_username";
        public static final String FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_FULL_NAME = "fb_full_name";

        //Conversations Table Columns
        public static final String CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
        public static final String CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_FRIEND_ID = "friend_id";
        public static final String CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_ENDED = "ended";


        //Database Creation SQL
        static final String CREATE_TABLE_FRIENDS = "CREATE TABLE "
                        + TABLE_FRIENDS + "("
                        + FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_USER_ID + " integer primary key,"
                        + FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_USERNAME + " text not null unique,"
                        + FRIENDS_COLUMN_FB_FULL_NAME + " text not null"
                        + ");";

        public static final String CREATE_TABLE_CONVERSATIONS = "CREATE TABLE "
                        + TABLE_CONVERSATIONS + "("
                        + CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                        + CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_USER_ID + " integer not null,"
                        + CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_FRIEND_ID + " integer not null,"
                        + CONVERSATIONS_COLUMN_ENDED + " integer not null"
                        + ");";

        public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
                super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                createFriendsTable(db);
                createConversationsTable(db);
        }

       private void createConversationsTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONVERSATIONS);
        }

        private void createFriendsTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRIENDS);
        }

         /**
         * @param table Name of the table to query
         * @param columns Array of column names to fetch
         * @param selection WHERE clause
         * @param selectionArgs WHERE clause arguments
         * @param groupBy GROUP BY clause
         * @param having HAVING clause
         * @param orderBy ORDER BY clause
         * @return Cursor to the requested rows
         */
        public Cursor getCursor(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {

                return getReadableDatabase().query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        }

        /**
         * Insert or replace a single row into a table
         * @param table Name of the table
         * @param nullColumnHack null hack
         * @param values Values to insert
         */
        public void putData(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                db.replace(table, nullColumnHack, values);
                db.close();
        }

        /**
         * Insert or replace an array of rows into a table
         * @param table Name of the table
         * @param nullColumnHack null hack
         * @param values Array of values to insert
         */
        public void putData(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues[] values) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                try {
                        db.beginTransaction();
                        for(ContentValues value : values) {
                                db.replace(table, nullColumnHack, value);
                        }
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                        db.endTransaction();
                }

                db.close();
        }

        /**
         * Delete rows from a table
         * @param table Name of the table
         * @param whereClause WHERE clause
         * @param whereArgs WHERE clause arguments
         */
        public void deleteData(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
                db.close();
        }

        /**
         * Update a table
         * @param table Name of the table
         * @param values Values to update
         * @param whereClause WHERE clause
         * @param whereArgs WHERE clause arguments
         */
        public void updateData(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
                db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
                db.close();
        }

}
```

Then in your activity, do `MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper()`, then you define the projections and selections you need when you call `dbHelper.getCuror()`, or the other methods.

This code was written when I was just beginning with programming, so from a structural POV, it's pretty badly written(at least, that's how I feel about it now), but this is how it'll work.

EDIT: Initialize your Database Helper with

```
databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(
                                        HomeActivity.this,
                                        MyDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                        MyDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I instantiate my SQLiteHelper source file in my activity? 
MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper() doesn't work. I put getActivity() or getContext() in MyDatabaseHelper(), but none of them works.

Comment: Actually, must I put everything in one source file? The SQLiteHelper as a subclass in my activity source file?

Comment: Nope.. You can place your SQLite Helper as a completely different class, that's recommended actually.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to instantiate your database.

Comment: OK, thanks. But why can't I instantiate my database? My SQLiteHelper source file is called CafeDB. I use CafeDB dataB=new CafeDB(); in my activity file, but it's not working.

Comment: A database helper has to be instantiated with a name and version, so see my source code for how I implemented that... :-)